# How can I make sure Excel reads the data and put them in SAP GUI?

Tags: excel, vba, sap-gui

Hi I am working on a code and I can't seem to figure out how to make Excel read the data to post in SAP GUI. For example I want to put in a document number in SAP ERP transaction code `FB02` and let Excel work from the first data cell to the last. But I can't seem to set the functions correctly.

In Excel I have data in column A ("Documentnr") and column B ("Inkooporder"). I want it to start from cell A2 and B2 to the last cell.

If using `Irow` I get:

> runtime error 1004.

This is my code:

```
Public Sub Ordernr()
    Dim W_Vouchernr As String
    Dim W_Inkooporder As String
    Dim lineitems As Long
 
    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(x1Up).Row

    Dim IRow as Long
    For Irow = 2 To LastRow
    
       'vouchernr
    If Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(iRow, 1) <> "" Then
        W_Vouchernr = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(iRow, 1)
    Else
        W_Vouchernr = "xxxxxxxxxx"
    End If

    'inkooporder
    If Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(iRow, 2) <> "" Then
        W_Inkooporder = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(iRow, 2)
    Else
        W_Inkooporder = "xxxxxxxxxx"
    End If

    If Not IsObject(SAPGuiApp) Then
        Set SapGuiAuto = GetObject("SAPGUI")
        Set SAPGuiApp = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine
    End If
    If Not IsObject(Connection) Then
        Set Connection = SAPGuiApp.Children(0)
    End If
    If Not IsObject(SAP_session) Then    
        Set SAP_session = Connection.Children(0)   
    End If

    If IsObject(Wscript) Then   
        Wscript.ConnectObject SAP_session, "on"
        Wscript.ConnectObject SAPGuiApp, "on"
    End If

    SAP_session.findById("wnd[0]").maximize
    SAP_session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").Text = "/nfb02"
    SAP_session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
    SAP_session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/txtRF05L-BELNR").Text = W_Vouchernr
    SAP_session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtRF05L-BUKRS").Text = companycode
    SAP_session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtRF05L-BUKRS").SetFocus
    SAP_session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtRF05L-BUKRS").caretPosition = 4
    SAP_session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0 
    SAP_session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlCTRL_CONTAINERBSEG/shellcont/shell")             
    .currentCellColumn
    SAP_session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlCTRL_CONTAINERBSEG/shellcont/shell")
    .currentCellColumn
    SAP_session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlCTRL_CONTAINERBSEG/shellcont/shell")
    .doubleClickCurrentCell
    SAP_session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtBSEG-SGTXT").Text = W_Inkooporder           
    SAP_session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtBSEG-SGTXT").SetFocus
    SAP_session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtBSEG-SGTXT").caretPosition = 14
    SAP_session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
    SAP_session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 11
    'Gets the message from the status bar and save it in column B
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(iRow, 3) =SAP_session.findById("wnd[0]/sbar").Text

Next Irow

End Sub
```

Comment: Well, what is `iRow` how is it defined? I see no loop around your code to iterate `iRow`. You probably need to find the last used cell (there are 1000 tutorials for this) and probably a loop `For iRow = 2 To LastRow … your code … Next iRow`

Comment: Well my code actually works now. Thanks for that. Now how do i make it so that it starts on the next cell? It only doest the first one

Comment: If you don't update the code in your question we cannot see what you are doing. Please [edit] your original question and update the code to what you changed it to.

Comment: Okay Sorry. I edited my code. So what is happening is that the code is not inserting the data from Column B. Instead its posting a blank. Searching with Column A and Gaining the statuscode does work however

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any idea of SAP, but you need to put the `For` loop around your complete code I think, and you need to define what the `LastRow` is.

So this might work:

```
Public Sub Ordernr()
    Dim W_Vouchernr As String
    Dim W_Inkooporder As String
    Dim lineitems As Long

    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'find last used row in column A

    Dim iRow As Long
    For iRow = 2 To LastRow 'loop from row 2 to last used row

        'vouchernr
        If Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(iRow, 1) <> "" Then
            W_Vouchernr = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(iRow, 1)
        Else
            W_Vouchernr = "xxxxxxxxxx"
        End If

        'inkooporder
        If Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(iRow, 2) <> "" Then
            W_Inkooporder = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(iRow, 2)
        Else
            W_Inkooporder = "xxxxxxxxxx"
        End If

        If Not IsObject(SAPGuiApp) Then
            Set SapGuiAuto = GetObject("SAPGUI")
            Set SAPGuiApp = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine
        End If
        If Not IsObject(Connection) Then
            Set Connection = SAPGuiApp.Children(0)
        End If
        If Not IsObject(SAP_session) Then    
            Set SAP_session = Connection.Children(0)   
        End If

        If IsObject(Wscript) Then   
            Wscript.ConnectObject SAP_session, "on"
            Wscript.ConnectObject SAPGuiApp, "on"
        End If

        SAP_session.findById("wnd[0]").maximize
        SAP_session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").Text = "/nfb02"
        SAP_session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
        SAP_session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/txtRF05L-BELNR").Text = W_Vouchernr
        SAP_session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtRF05L-BUKRS").Text = companycode
        SAP_session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtRF05L-BUKRS").SetFocus
        SAP_session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtRF05L-BUKRS").caretPosition = 4
        SAP_session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0 
        SAP_session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlCTRL_CONTAINERBSEG/shellcont/shell").currentCellColumn
        SAP_session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlCTRL_CONTAINERBSEG/shellcont/shell").currentCellColumn
        SAP_session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlCTRL_CONTAINERBSEG/shellcont/shell").doubleClickCurrentCell
        SAP_session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtBSEG-SGTXT").Text = W_Inkooporder           
        SAP_session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtBSEG-SGTXT").SetFocus
        SAP_session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtBSEG-SGTXT").caretPosition = 14
        SAP_session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
        SAP_session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 11

        'Gets the message from the status bar and save it in column B
        Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(iRow, 3) =SAP_session.findById("wnd[0]/sbar").Text
    Next iRow 'iterate one row down

End Sub
```

Comment: I get a 1004 runtime error on the Line    LastRow = Worksheets("Sheets2").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(x1Up).Row

Comment: @Joshua44 please use copy/paste don't type yourself: it is `xlUp` not `x1Up` (note the number `One` vs lower `L`) and `Worksheets("Sheet2")` not `Worksheets("Sheets2")`. Don't produce typos just copy/paste code.

Comment: My bad! So now it still only takes 1 row. its taking the 2nd row now instead of the first. How do i make it so that it starts from the first to last?

Comment: Come on in your question you said *"I want it to start from cell A2"* now you tell you want to start from row 1? Be clear about what you want in your question! • Also this loop runs from row 2 to last row: `For iRow = 2 To LastRow`. Debug your code going through it by using F8 and see what value `LastRow` is. I cannot help you with the SAP part, but the loop runs from 2 … LastRow.

Comment: @Joshua44 it might be that `xlDown` will fail try `LastRow = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(Worksheets("Sheet2").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row` instead